# How to develop apps that goes inside the Facebook Timeline?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

I've seen the new facebook timeline and it seems there is going to be a way for developers to create apps there. But I can't find any documentation for it.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook has done a great job documenting how to work with the new Open Graph API. Consult [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/tutorial/) document.